# How can I create a Java memory dump via API?

Tags: java, api, memory, dump

Is it possible to create a memory dump via API from inside of the process? If not can I use jvisualvm via command line to create a dump from my process?

I want add this feature to the administrator website of an hosted service.

Answer (score 1):

You can check https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java which describes a way to programmatically create a heap dump for the HotSpot VM using a [`com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html).